# Can one constraint on a command object check the result of another?

Tags: grails, command-objects, grails-constraints

This is a simple example that doesn't work, I'm wondering if there is a way to validate `a` inside the validator block of `b` if it hasn't already been validated.

Example how I thought it would work:

```
static constraints =
{
    a nullable: false
    b validator: { val, obj ->
        if(obj.errors.hasFieldError('a'))
        {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Note: in this scenario `obj.errors.hasFieldError('a')` returns false even if `a` is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any guarantee of the order the constraints are checked, and it's unlikely that it would have anything to do with the order specified in the `constraints` block.

However, in addition to the common one-arg custom validator that passes you the current value for that field and the two-arg validator you show where you also get access to the domain class instance, there's a three-arg variant (unfortunately it doesn't seem to be covered in the Grails reference docs ...) where the third argument is the Spring `Errors` instance. If you define a three-arg validator, GORM ignores any return value since it's assumed that you'll be working directly with the `Errors` instance, calling one or more of the different `rejectValue` methods yourself for any validation issues.

So you could remove from the `constraints` block any standard validations that you want to run yourself and use this approach instead. You can find more information about working with the `Errors` object in [the Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#validation).

Comment: Sounds like a great idea, I have multiple fields I'd like to check so I would need to have them all outside the constraints closure.  I'm not too familiar with closures, is it possible to call the constraints closure in a method and pass it some field names to act on?